# I can't prevent the jQuery card blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please guys help me. I'm new in web developing. I had to create a find pairs web app. It works correctly but I have only one problem.

Every time when I cannot find a pair of one item the last card is blinks once. I have a problem with the jQuery delay, show and hide. Here is a snippet from my code. Thank you!

```
else {
    $('.' + title1).delay(800).hide(0);
    $('.' + title2).delay(800).hide(0);

    $('[title=' + title1 + ']').delay(800).show(0).addClass('animated flipInx'); 
    $('[title=' + title2 + ']').delay(800).show(0).addClass('animated flipInx');

    points = points - 2;

    //set disable
    $('.flip').css('pointer-events', 'none');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flip').css('pointer-events', 'unset');
    }, 1701);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to fix a problem we can't see. Could you please add a working example of the issue in a snippet

Comment: Sorry I can't at the moment. :( You have to imagine the situation the next: after I flipped two card, the last one is vibrating once (hiding and showing).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please have a read of the [tour] including [ask] and then  [mcve].

Comment: you can't is different from you won't